# Can I create a RegEx set in containing meta-characters?

Tags: python, regex

I have corpus made up of thousands of strings. I want to run a regular expression over each string to find the beginning and ending of specific words, including any punctuation.

I have tried to write a RegEx which includes a set containing a number of possible word beginnings/endings including regular characters like space, comma, full stop, etc. It also needs to include meta-characters like new line and string-end.

Here is an example of a string and the kind of regular expression I've been trying to use:

```
text = "abcd aacd. abcd\n adcd"

my_re = re.compile(r'[ ^]a\wcd[ .,$]')
pat_iter = my_re.finditer(text)

for i in pat_iter:
    print(i.group())
```

The output I would like to get from this would be:

```
abcd 
aacd.
abcd

adcd
```

Unfortunately, I can't use meta-characters like `^`, `\n` and `$` within a square-bracket set, `[]`.

Is there any way to un-escape these characters within a set so that they can be used as meta-characters?

Edit:
I don't want to separate these words using something like splitting wherever there is a space, like:

```
text = text.split(" ")
```

It needs to be with a RegEx like I described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex which adds an or (`|`) case for the end condition:

```
'a\wcd[ \.\n]|a\wcd$'
```

**Example**:

```
import re

text = "abcd aacd. abcd\n adcd"

my_re = re.compile(r'a\wcd[ \.\n]|a\wcd$')
pat_iter = my_re.finditer(text)

for i in pat_iter:
    print(i.group())

# abcd
# aacd.
# abcd

# adcd
```

Comment: This seems to be the best solution, thanks. I went with a slight variation of your suggested RegEx, just to make it closer to what I'd originally wanted to use, and because within a set `\.` seems to be used as meta-character. This is what I went with: `re.compile(r'(^|[ \n])?(a\wcd)([ ,.\n\$]|$)')`

Answer (score 1):

You might use

```
\ba\wcd[.,]?\s*
```

In parts

- `\ba` Match wordboundary followed by `a`
- `\w` Match a word character
- `cd` Match `cd` literally
- `[.,]?` Match an optional `.` or `,`
- `\s*` Match 0+ whitespace chars which will also match newlines

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o4y24c/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/YObIVE)

For example

```
import re
text = "abcd aacd. abcd\n adcd"

my_re = re.compile(r'\ba\wcd[.,]?\s*')
pat_iter = my_re.finditer(text)

for i in pat_iter:
    print(i.group())
```

Output

```
abcd 
aacd. 
abcd

adcd
```

Comment: I do need to include the end-of-string character. But the `\ba` might be an interesting alternative. How does it determine what a word boundary is? Spacing?

Comment: Perhaps [this page](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) can be helpful about word boundaries. Perhaps you could also prepend `\s*` like https://regex101.com/r/2ttCm9/1

Answer (score 0):

Would this regex work? `[ \^]*a\wcd[ .,$]*` (tested with the very helpful https://regex101.com).

Comment: This seems to match the literal $ at the end of words, which isn't something I want. It finds the word at the end of the string here, but this is only because * means it doesn't have to match anything in the set. I need it to be required to match at least one thing in the set.